# Bad performance of c++ for arithmetic operations

Tags: r, performance, rcpp

I have written a pretty easy function using only arithmetic operations in R and c++ (using rcpp). Comparing the two functions reveals that my c++ implementations is way slower than my R code which leaves me quite puzzled.

The c++ version:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector dn_cpp(NumericVector x, NumericVector sigma, NumericVector mu) {
  return   1/(sqrt(2*M_PI)*sigma) * exp(pow((x-mu),2)/(-2*pow(sigma, 2)) );
}
```

The R version:

```
dn_r <- function(x, sigma, mu) {
  1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma) * exp((x-mu)^2/(-2*sigma^2)  )
}
```

Comparing both:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  dn_r(1,1,1),
  dn_cpp(1,1,1),
  times = 10000
)

# Unit: nanoseconds
#             expr  min   lq      mean median     uq     max neval
#    dn_r(1, 1, 1)  509  567  667.1547    627  715.5   12690 10000
#  dn_cpp(1, 1, 1) 1094 1242 1713.8351   1335 1479.0 3192711 10000
```

Can anybody explain why my c++ function lacks performance?

Comment: It is a some degenerate example of a _single_ arithmetic expression, evaluated once.  The is no R behaviour here: it just calls the _same_ special functions.  So what you see may be attributed the small bits of overhead from conveniently wrapping C++ via `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual, [李哲源](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/%e6%9d%8e%e5%93%b2%e6%ba%90) and [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) are completely right; for these sorts of operations there is absolutely no reason to expect the C++ version to be faster than the R version for the data you called the functions with. I add this answer only to demonstrate the suggestion by [李哲源](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/%e6%9d%8e%e5%93%b2%e6%ba%90):

```
microbenchmark(
    dn_r(1,1,1),
    dn_cpp(1,1,1),
    times = 10000
)

Unit: microseconds
            expr   min    lq      mean median    uq       max neval
   dn_r(1, 1, 1) 4.061 4.390  7.569112  4.869 5.175 26308.271 10000
 dn_cpp(1, 1, 1) 8.362 9.025 12.148559  9.265 9.653  5834.242 10000

microbenchmark(
    dn_r(rnorm(1e3), 1, 1),
    dn_cpp(rnorm(1e3), 1, 1),
    times = 10000
) 

Unit: microseconds
                      expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq      max
   dn_r(rnorm(1000), 1, 1) 298.134 303.631 313.9681 305.453 308.7080 4111.497
 dn_cpp(rnorm(1000), 1, 1) 199.949 205.571 214.6522 207.414 210.5015 3859.939

microbenchmark(
    dn_r(rnorm(1e5), 1, 1),
    dn_cpp(rnorm(1e5), 1, 1),
    times = 10000
) 

Unit: milliseconds
                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
   dn_r(rnorm(1e+05), 1, 1) 28.60395 29.28238 30.85371 29.46879 29.95939 160.0769
 dn_cpp(rnorm(1e+05), 1, 1) 18.89528 19.44148 20.10618 19.60433 19.75410 143.7250
```

With short vectors, the additional overhead means the R version will be faster, while you can get some performance gain with longer vectors.